# Dynamic creation of beans in Spring

Tags: spring, dynamic, javabeans, creation

Is there a way in spring wherein we can read the fields of a bean from the DB table and create a complete bean class - with getters and setters on server startup????

I require this to make my application completely configurable...as in if I have to add a new field in future , all I would require would be adding a field in the db and the bean setters and getters would be available to me.

Thanks

Comment: Ask yourself if dynamic generation at runtime is what you really need/want. If so, you'd be better off with Ruby/Rails or Groovy/Grails.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try approaches for dynamically registering beans . You could use the [BeanDefinitionBuilder](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/beans/factory/support/BeanDefinitionBuilder.html) for this purpose . See a sample [here](http://shayanth.blogspot.com/2009/10/dynamic-bean-creation-in-spring.html) . But as @Darren says , It's not a wise idea to creak a bean via DB lookup .

Answer (score 1):

1: Improve your accept-rate

2: You might benefit from something like an ORM approach (Hibernate or JPA). Another slightly different approach that might suite you is the Active Record pattern as implemented in, forinstance, [ActiveJDBC](http://code.google.com/p/activejdbc/).

Spring does not, in itself, offer anything like what you are after, but using spring-jpa together with Hibernate might get you a bit closer towards your goal. If, OTOH, you want auto-generated code you could also look at something like [Spring-Roo](http://www.springsource.org/spring-roo)

Answer (score 0):

You might want to think about this a little more. Even if you made your fields totally configurable, you will still have to write the code that accesses them. And given that you are going to have to write code anyway, might as well keep everything in code. It's much simpler that way.

Comment: hmm...yeah ...get your point Darren..any other way we can do this...My use case is as follows:

We have a jsp form ...in case we have new fields coming up in future , we just want to handle it via configuration...this would include binding form fields with java fields, apply validations on these fields..etc..

Comment: It will be significantly harder to write the code that makes the application this configurable than to write the code you need when you need it. If you really really want to drive this stuff via configuration then you don't want to be messing around trying to generate classes on the fly. You'd probably be better off using hashmaps or other data structure.